# Prevent Websocket from spamming my console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, websocket, socket.io

I'm using `Node.js`, `Socket.io` and `Websocket`.

Every time I emit something, it writes it in my `console.log`. I emit a lot of stuff so my console.log becomes totally unusable for debugging purposes.

Is there any way to prevent `Websocket` from writing all emit events on my console?

An example of what is written:

> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"stuff...."}
>
> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"more stuff...."}
>
> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"even more stuff...."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set log level option to 0 like this:

```
   var io = require('socket.io').listen(port, host);
   io.set('log level', 0);
```